# How to depend only on the upstream version of a Debian package?

Tags: debian, dpkg

I tried to build a Debian package, which depends on Nodejs. I have specified my dependency in the control file of the package this way:

```
Depends: nodejs (>= 10.24.0)
```

But when I try to install the package, I get a dependency error:

```
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of xxx:
 xxx depends on nodejs (>= 10.24.0); however:
  Version of nodejs on system is 10.24.0~dfsg-1~deb10u1.
```

How can I specify the dependency in the control file such that it gets also satisfied by a package having the "~dfsg" suffix? I can not find it in the [documentation](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-relationships.html).

I tried to use a globing pattern, but that does not work at all:

```
 'Depends' field, reference to 'nodejs': version '10.24.0*': invalid character in version number
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The workaround here is to add a tilde:

```
Depends: nodejs (>= 10.24.0~)
```

See [What does a tilde (~) mean at the end of a dependency requirement in a deb file or in apt?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/703950/86440) for details.